# Why not `mem::drop(self)` here?

Tags: runtime

I feel a little confused about the usage of `mem::forget(...)` when reading `impl Imbalance<T::Balance> for PositiveImbalance<T, I>` in `pallet-balances` pallet.

Accord the `forget` docs:

> Takes ownership and “forgets” about the value without running its destructor.

Why not use `drop` to dispose of the value forever, any specific reason for this?

```rs
fn split(self, amount: T::Balance) -> (Self, Self) {
    let first = self.0.min(amount);
    let second = self.0 - first;

    mem::forget(self); // here
    (Self(first), Self(second))
}
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to leave a comment there, since it might be not obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [trait docs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0f6b5734e8ff52199987b496b2ef7bfd51655198/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/imbalance.rs#L71) - `fn split` is meant to return two more instances of `Self` that still need to be handled. You cannot `drop` an `Imbalance` that's yet to be handled because it has a [custom `Drop` impl](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0f6b5734e8ff52199987b496b2ef7bfd51655198/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1101L111) that adjusts `TotalIssuance` when an imbalance gets dropped from memory:

```rust
impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Drop for PositiveImbalance<T, I> {
    /// Basic drop handler will just square up the total issuance.
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        <super::TotalIssuance<T, I>>::mutate(
            |v| *v = v.saturating_add(self.0)
        );
    }
}

impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Drop for NegativeImbalance<T, I> {
    /// Basic drop handler will just square up the total issuance.
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        <super::TotalIssuance<T, I>>::mutate(
            |v| *v = v.saturating_sub(self.0)
        );
    }
}
```